# wrong json output in python

Tags: python, json

I'm sure this is simple but my heads not with it today, I'm trying to output a JSON file in this format:

```
{"A": {"B": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}}
```

My code so far is:

```
jsonobj = {"A":{"B":[]
                      },
           }
var1 = 1
jsonobj["A"]["B"].append(dict(f=var1))
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(jsonobj, f)
print jsonobj
```

As you can guess its a mismatch of code from StackOverflow and outputting wrong,

```
{'A': {'B': [{'f': 1}]}}
```

Sure it's an easy one, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you do `jsonobj = {"A": {"B": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}}`, what's the dynamic part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
jsonobj["A"]["B"].append(var1)
```

If it is like

```
var1 = [1,1,1,1]
jsonobj["A"]["B"].extend(var1)
```

Comment: This does *not* produce `{"A": [{"B": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}]}` though which OP said was the desired result.